# Can java JNI load native funciton without file?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

I'm wondering how to write a java program that load native funciton from itself.
I just want to use the simple native function in lib(which raw data was stored inside java code).

Usually load native is like this, which will load lib from file system:

```java
public class HelloJNI {
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("hello"); // Load native library hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
   }
   private native void sayHello();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new HelloJNI().sayHello();
   }
}
```

However for some reason, I want do this with only one .java file. For example, I write "libhello.so" from java to file and load it:

```java
public class HelloJNI  {
    public static native void sayHello();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./libhello.so");
        fos.write(Base64.getDecoder().decode("base64encode of libhello.so"));
        fos.close();
        System.load(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/libhello.so");
        new HelloJNI().sayHello();

    }
}
```

Since I write data in program to file and load the file I just wrote only to use "System.load()", I want to know if I can just load from program rather than write to file and load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically asking if you can call arbitrary code in memory you control.  This is something that is technically possible... the JIT compiler of the JVM is doing it all the time.  But I think you will need at least one native library loaded through the standard mechanism to get started.  There is no way to do this directly from Java that I am aware of, so at this point I think you first need a basic JNI library to provide the hooks needed.

Project Panama may change this, see:  https://github.com/openjdk/panama-foreign/blob/foreign-jextract/doc/panama_ffi.md